# Merging 2 key Arrays into 1 Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have 2 arrays, 1 called $person and the other called $classes. I'd like to merge the 2 together into 1 array and assign a name to item in the new merged array. Therefore creating an associative array as opposed to using keys that array_merge seems to be made by default using the array_merge function. (For clarity 1 person has multiple classes.)

Currently I have this:

($person)

```
[1]=>
   array(2) {
     ["Name"]=>
       string(1) "Bobby Moore"
     ["Age"]=>
       string(18) "36"
```

($classes)

```
   [1]=>
     array(2) {
     [0]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Class ID"]=>
           string(1) "12"
         ["Class Title"]=>
           string(18) "Math 101"
     [1]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Class ID"]=>
           string(1) "13"
         ["Class Title"]=>
           string(18) "Math 102"
     [1]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Class ID"]=>
           string(1) "14"
         ["Class Title"]=>
           string(18) "Math 103"
```

Is it possible to get the following result?

```
   [person]=>
     array(1) {
     [0]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Name"]=>
           string(1) "Bobby Moore"
         ["Ages"]=>
           string(18) "35"
   [Classes]=>
     array(2) {
     [0]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Class ID"]=>
           string(1) "12"
         ["Class Title"]=>
           string(18) "Math 101"
     [1]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Class ID"]=>
           string(1) "13"
         ["Class Title"]=>
           string(18) "Math 102"
     [1]=>
       array(11) {
         ["Class ID"]=>
           string(1) "14"
         ["Class Title"]=>
           string(18) "Math 103"
```

Currently I'm using array_merge($person ,$classes); which unfortunately is an array sorted by keys.

I hope this makes sense! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just a matter of doing

```
$new_array = array( "person" => $person_array, "classes" => $class_array );
```

Comment: Additionally you would need to specify the key value of the each array in order to prevent an additional layer being added. i.e. $person_array[0].

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you very much!